# Restrict autocomplete to an array of polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map in which I want to use autocomplete, but only within some areas. I have managed to create bounds as a recangle with two coordinates:

```
const southWest = new google.maps.LatLng( 55.25877294, 12.45849609 );
const northEast = new google.maps.LatLng( 56.30282487, 14.28497314 );
const defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );
```

But what I actually need is to have an array of coordinates as bounds, so that I can't search outside of the areas.

Here is my current solution: [JS-FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/u4tghbvp/6/)

(I have some example coordinates in there on line 47 and below, if needed)

Comment: Check if there is an open feature request and if not, file one here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3 as this is not (yet) available in the API.